# Toggle Bootsrap 4 modal screen using ajaxStart - ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How do I open the modal screen on ajaxStart and close it on ajaxStop?

I have tried a lot of the answers on Stack, but for some reason, it won't do what I am asking.

I have the following Bootstrap 4 modal:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal"  data-target="#myModal" name="loadingModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="~/images/spinner.gif" />
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following JQuery:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#loadingModal').toggle();          
        alert('Ajax happening');
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
        alert('Ajax stopping');
    });
```

It works fine when I use a button event, but I want to do it while the Ajax call is doing its work.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a direct answer, the issue I have is that there are a bunch of libraries being sent over by the _Layout in the netcore shared folder. Along with the CDNs I have put in the page, this caused conflicts and prevented the modal from working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show/hide the modal you can use:

- $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
- $('#loadingModal').modal('hide')

Consider to hide the modal after a timeout: for instance after 0,5 seconds.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
    console.log('Ajax happening');
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    setTimeout(() => $('#loadingModal').modal('hide'), 500);
    console.log('Ajax complete');
});



//
// an ajax call....
//
$.get('https://api.github.com/users/defunkt', function() {
  console.log('ajax end');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal"  data-target="#myModal" name="loadingModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have spent hours trying to work this out, so it must have something to do with the libraries I am loading. Can you tell me if they look correct, I have updated to question with the CDns.

Comment: Yes you are right. The order and the libraries you use are different from the one you can see in my snippet. Moreover, don't include jQuery twice. See the differences between my snippet and your code.

Comment: It's netcore...itnhas preloaded a ton of libraries.